# Ubuntu 21.10 starts with search bar opened

Tags: gnome, configuration, panel, 21.10, menu-bar

I have several machines all running Ubuntu 21.10.
One of them starts with the search bar opened, like when you press the "windows" key:

[image: picture]

The machine is an embedded PC (ApolloLake-based) with no keyboard.
With other Ubuntu versions (i.e. 20.04) there is no such a behavior.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior indeed has changed with Gnome Shell 40, which comes with Ubuntu 21.10. To revert to the old behavior, install the Gnome Shell extension [No overview at start-up](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/) by fthx.

Comment: It seems it wants to use a browser to change the settings. But on that machine I have no browser installed. Is there a way to set the "no overview" behavior from console?

Comment: Another weird thing is only one machine has this behavior, but I have 4 running 21.10.

Comment: Gnome shell extensions can be installed from the terminal.

Comment: A bit more detailed explanation is welcome! I tried to copy the 2 files into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-no-overview@fthx.v11` and reboot, but the "Extension" application does not show the new one.

Comment: There are tutorials out there that teach how to manually install extensions. There is also a command line tool, `gnome-shell-extension-install`. There are probably questions out here about manually installing extensions.